# Is there a specific name for iOS list-like buttons?

Tags: ios, swift, list, button

I'm gonna make a half presented modal like you all can see in the iPhone's note app, but I was wondering there is a specific name for making this button like the image below?

[image]

(It's not related to this post but...) I was watching [the UIDatepicker's video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10205/) the other day, and the guy on the video also talked about the pull-down menu. I know the pull-down menu is not the one I'm trying to make, but its appearance looks similar to what I want to create now (I mean buttons in a list), so I was wondering if there is a specific UI for making this list like buttons or is it just like a normal button in a row and I need to customize them like a list?

Comment: I think you are looking for [`UITableView.Style.insetGrouped`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/style/insetgrouped).

Comment: They are not "buttons". It is, as you have said, a list.